# How to know when exec() function is finish?

Tags: php, exec

I have an exec function in php file that execs a bash script. It script calls fmpeg to transcode a video file.

How can I know when transcoding is finish??

```
$script = "/opt/lamp../name.sh"
exec("$script $videoIn $id")
```

I will try using next code but it doesn't workd.

```
if (exec("$script $videoIn $id"))
{
//print on screen that the video has been transcoded
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `exec()` will return when the executed command is finished. My guess is that the command fails somehow (possibly because you're not using [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) and [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)).

Comment: Where I have to use escapeshellcmd()?

Comment: ok solved. the video input file hasn't execution permisses. Thanks

Comment: @skiria: If my answer solved your problem, you should *accept* it (i.e. press the hollow tick left to it.) If you don't accept answers to your questions, less and less people will be ready to help you.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. OP solved it another way. This answer shouldn't have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your php script waits for the `exec`'d command to be finished before going on.

**exec does not return the command's return value**.

```
string exec  (  string $command  [,  array &$output  [,  int &$return_var  ]] )
```

you have to provide a var where that value will be written.

Comment: If I have a php code, next line after exec, when will be run? When exec() is finish?